# erro aqui no meu script de fazer o personagem dar respawn (load.level)

Tags: unity3d, jogos

Quando eu coloco esse seguinte script no `unity` e logo após o associo com uma forma transparente (sem física) e clico no play pra testar, dá um erro falando que não da pra jogar (olha a print), alguém pode me ajudar? tem algo errado no script?

ele tá escrito aqui em baixo....
(desculpe minha inexperiência tentei ser o mais detalhista possível!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Fall : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Application.LoadLevel("level1"­);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa adicionar a scene **level1** na Build Settings, para o jogo ter conhecimento sobre ela. Quando você chama LoadLevel, a Unity não sabe que o arquivo level1 é uma scene parte do jogo.

*"Mas a scene está na pasta do jogo".* Sim, porém só porque ela está ali não significa obrigatoriamente que ela será incluída na build.

Vá em File -> Build Settings:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então arraste a sua scene para a seção "Scenes In Build":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]